# How to set android:button="@null" of RadioButton in java code rather than xml

Tags: java, android, radio-button

How to  set  android:button="@null"  of  RadioButton  in java code  rather than xml. I want to set it in java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is to set an empty `StateListDrawable`:

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code:

```
android:button="@null"
```

is equivalent in Java to:

```
radio.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in java code to set custom button for RadiButton :

```
 StateListDrawable mState1 = new StateListDrawable();
 mState1.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed },getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button3_pressed));
 mState1.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused },getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button3_focused));
 mState1.addState(new int[] {},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button3_up));
 radioButton.setButtonDrawable(mState1);
```

Comment: radioButton.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());